Split XML based on Xpath
I am in need to split the XML file based on this Xpath //book/part/chapter/sect
XML coding:
<book>
<prelims>This is prelims</prelims>
<part>This is part
<chapter>This is Chapter
<level><sect>This is sect1</sect></level>
<level><sect>This is sect2</sect></level>
<level><sect>This is sect3</sect></level>
<level><sect>This is sect4</sect></level>
</chapter>
</part>
</book>

Split XML output 1 (Prelims if exist then will split with the first sect):
<book>
<prelims>This is prelims</prelims>
<part>This is part
<chapter>This is Chapter
<level><sect>This is sect1</sect></level>
</chapter>
</part>
</book>

Split XML output 2:
<book>
<part>This is part
<chapter>This is Chapter
<level><sect>This is sect2</sect></level>
</chapter>
</part>
</book>

Split XML output 3:
<book>
<part>This is part
<chapter>This is Chapter
<level><sect>This is sect3</sect></level>
</chapter>
</part>
</book>

Split XML output 4:
<book>
<part>This is part
<chapter>This is Chapter
<level><sect>This is sect3</sect></level>
</chapter>
</part>
</book>

I am struck with the below XSLT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="//sect">        
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <xsl:variable name="increment" select="position()"/>
     <xsl:result-document href="try{$increment}.xml">         
         <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
     </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


That path //book/prelims/part/chapter/sect doesn't select anything as the part element(s) are not children of a or the prelims. So the requirement "I am in need to split the XML file based on this Xpath //book/prelims/part/chapter/sect" does not make much sense.

EDIT after change example in question from
<sect>This is sect1</sect>
to
<level><sect>This is sect1</sect></level>
Try this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Use the root as context to build your splits -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="book/part/chapter/level/sect">
      <xsl:variable name="increment" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:result-document href="try{$increment}.xml">         
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*">
          <xsl:with-param name="increment" select="$increment" tunnel="yes" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Only use prelims if its's the first result-document -->
  <xsl:template match="prelims">
    <xsl:param name="increment" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test="$increment=1">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Use that level that is equal to the postion of the result-document 
  Since we might also have a text-node (This is Chapter) we use the count(preceding-sibling::level)
  -->
  <xsl:template match="level">
    <xsl:param name="increment" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test="$increment - 1 =  count(preceding-sibling::level)">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#apply-imports has xsl:next-match so that <xsl:if test="$increment=1"><xsl:call-template name="copy"/></xsl:if> could simply be <xsl:if test="$increment=1"><xsl:next-match/></xsl:if> as you have the identity copy set up.

Nice one. Will change it

Thanks for the update. I will check on this

Hi @SiebeJongebloed, There is a small change in the Input coding and the splitted output. The level element is added in for every sect element. So I have modified the template match of sect as below. But the below coding is not generating. Kindly check
<xsl:template match="sect">
<xsl:param name="increment" tunnel="yes"/>
<xsl:if test="$increment - 1 =  count(parent::label/preceding-sibling::sect)">
xsl:next-match/
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

Did the answer solved your original question? If yes see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.
About your change, please ask a new question and will have a look.

@Siebe Jongebloed yes the solution is correct

@SiebeJongebloed I have accepted it. Please check the same question with the modified input and output
